# Does $\left|\log^2{x}\right|=\log^2x$ hold true?

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

I have a question about absolute values. Does the following hold true? $$\left|\log^2{x}\right|=\log^2x$$

In one problem my textbook removes the absolute from $\left|\log^{2/3}x\right|$.

In theory yes, because the absolute value of $|x|=x$ if x is positive or equal to $0$. Sorry for the dumb question and thanks.

Comment: It's not dumb to ask questions!

Comment: For $\left|\log^{2/3}x\right|$ we can remove the absolute value assuming $\log x\ge 0$ that is $x\ge 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with logarithms. For *every* real function $f$ it is true that $(\forall x\in D_f):\bigl\lvert f^2(x)\bigr\rvert=f^2(x)$ simply because $f^2(x)\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course for $x>0$ since $\log^2 x \ge 0$ we have

$$\left|\log^2{x}\right|=\log^2x$$

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I had the same frustration. Generally, we do not accept no integers powers of negative numbers such as $(-1)^{3/2}$ or $(-1)^{\pi}$ e.t.c, but in case where we have a rational number with odd denominator such as $2/3$,  $6/5$  etc, it is possible to write $(-1)^{2/3}$ which of course is equal to $\left((-1)^2\right)^{1/3}=\left((-1)^{1/3}\right)^2$ .

Comment: Sadly there is no *of course* here: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%5E(2%2F3)) gives $(-1)^{2/3} = -\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$ but $\left((-1)^2\right)^{1/3} =1$

Comment: @Henry    So If I undertasnd correctly, $\log^{2/3}x$ is imaginery, in case $x\lt1$ ?

Comment: I would say *possibly complex* rather than *imaginary*

Comment: @Henry You are right, complex. And so If I am correct for real $x$ the functions $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ and $f(x)=\left(x^{2}\right)^{1/3}$ are not the same?

Comment: For positive $x$ they are usually taken to be the same.  For negative $x$ there are likely to be issues of multiple or principal values

Comment: @Henry, I am a bit confused now, I always thought that $f(x)=x^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{x}$, $x\in\Bbb{R}$ has only one value. If you can sent me a nice referrence it would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If your function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$  is defined solely for $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ you may be correct when $x$ is negative and real, but if it is defined for $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ on principal values you may be incorrect when $x$ has a negative real part and a zero imaginary part.  Which is why my original comment said *possibly complex*